# Why can’t Scala infer the path of a path-dependent type—even from an explicit self-reference?

Tags: scala, type-inference, path-dependent-type, type-projection

I'd like to pass an object to a function that accepts an argument with a projected type, and get Scala to deduce that the object's type comes from the object that encloses it. Here's some simple code to illustrate the difficulty:

```
trait Cult { cult_ =>
  case class CultLeader(personality: Personality) {
    val cult = cult_
    val follower = personality.attractFollower(this)
  }
  case class Follower(leader: CultLeader, name: String)
}

trait Personality {
  def attractFollower(leader: Cult#CultLeader) =
    leader.cult.Follower(leader, "Fred") // <-- THIS LINE FAILS TO COMPILE
}
```

In other words, a CultLeader’s Personality should attract a Follower to the same Cult as the CultLeader.

The Scala 2.11.2 compiler says:

```
TypeProjection.scala:11: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Cult#CultLeader
 required: leader.cult.CultLeader
    leader.cult.Follower(leader, "Fred")
                         ^
```

It compiles and runs correctly if I add a cast, like this:

```
    leader.cult.Follower(leader.asInstanceOf[leader.cult.CultLeader], "Fred")
```

That seems clumsy and it introduces run-time checking for something that ought to be deducible at compile-time. At least I have a workaround. How can I get the Scala compiler to deduce that `leader`'s type is in fact `leader.cult.CultLeader`?

I'd prefer not to pass `cult` as another argument to `attractFollower`. In my actual code, that could result in a lot of ugly passing around of the `cult` parameter—when it really shouldn't need to be passed at all.

Answer (score 10):

The simple way is:

```
trait Cult { cult_ =>
  case class CultLeader(personality: Personality) {
    val cult = cult_
    val follower = personality.attractFollower(this)
  }
  case class Follower(leader: Cult#CultLeader, name: String) // <-- Cult#CultLeader here
}

trait Personality {
  def attractFollower(leader: Cult#CultLeader) =
    leader.cult.Follower(leader, "Fred")   
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined trait Cult
defined trait Personality
```

Here you're explicitly specifying that `Follower` can take any projection, which you're actually trying to force with `asInstanceOf`.

---

There is another way to do that:

```
trait Cult {
  case class CultLeader(personality: Personality) {
    def fl(name: String) = Follower(this, name)
    val follower = personality.attractFollower(this)
  }
  case class Follower(leader: CultLeader, name: String)
}

trait Personality {
  def attractFollower(leader: Cult#CultLeader) = leader.fl("Fred")
}
```

or

```
trait Cult {
  case class CultLeader(personality: Personality) { ld =>
    val follower = personality.attractFollower(this)
    case class Follower(name: String) { val leader = ld }
  }
}

trait Personality {
  def attractFollower(leader: Cult#CultLeader) = leader.Follower("Fred")   
}
```

---

**UPDATE:** This example could make it more clear why Scala is doing what she's doing:

```
trait Cult { cult_ =>
  case class CultLeader(personality: Personality) {
    val cult: Cult = cult_ //could be new Cult{} as well
    val l = this.asInstanceOf[cult.CultLeader] //We have to do asInstanceOf here because Scala have no glue (from type signature) that this cult is same as cult_
    val follower = personality.attractFollower(this)
  }

  case class Follower(leader: CultLeader, name: String)
}

trait Personality {
  def attractFollower(leader: Cult#CultLeader) = 
    leader.cult.Follower(leader.l, "Fred")   
} 

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.
defined trait Cult
defined trait Personality
```

And here is **final** solution which does what you want in correct way:

```
trait Cult { cult_ =>
  case class CultLeader(personality: Personality) { 
    val cult: cult_.type = cult_
    val l: cult.CultLeader = this
    val follower = personality.attractFollower(this)
  }

  case class Follower(leader: CultLeader, name: String)

}

trait Personality {
  def attractFollower(leader: Cult#CultLeader) = 
    leader.cult.Follower(leader.l, "Fred")   
}  

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.
defined trait Cult
defined trait Personality
```

The catch here is that `cult_.type` is path-dependent (projected).

Comment: Is there a way to require that a Follower be from the same Cult as the Follower's `leader`?

Comment: Yes, that was your prvious solution - however you can't pass a leader of **any** cult to follower which requires a leader from **concrete** cult - there is no way to check it in compile-time as Scala doesn't know how exactly your `attractFollower` is gonna be called (it could be a code outside build module). So your solution is like passing `Any` when function requires `Int`. So no way to require concrete cult-projection and pass any projection simultaneusly - it's logically incorrect.

Comment: Even though `attractFollower` can be called from anywhere, shouldn't it be able to create a Follower of the same Cult as the leader that was passed to `attractFollower`?

Comment: I've added several other ways

Comment: Hmm, #2 looks good. Apparently the trick is to call the constructor from source code that physically sits inside the enclosing class definition. #3 makes Follower path-dependent on the CultLeader object, which I don't think is right since a Follower should be able to switch between CultLeaders, or a different Personality should attract different kinds of Followers, etc. I'm mainly seeking understanding of the type-inference problem and how to get around it in general. #2 might do it; I'll experiment with my real application code (which has nothing to do with cults).

Comment: @BenKovitz I'm glad that your real application code has nothing to do with cults :)

Comment: @BenKovitz I've updated the answer with final solution and explanation